# Apache 2.4 service error 1053 when starting

Tags: php, apache, service, configuration, server

Everything was going fine until I restarted my server after making a small change to the `php.ini` (change error_log location). Now it wont start at all even after I changed the `php.ini` back to the way it was. I get an error that says:

> "Windows could not start the Apache2.4 service on Local Computer.
>
> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control
>   request in a timley fashion."

Funny thing is though, the error pops up almost as soon as I click start.

Comment: What error is in event viewer and in apache's error.log?

Comment: It was not logging any new errors.

Comment: I ended up solving the problem by replacing the entire apache24 folder with a fresh download from Apache. Weird thing is that I used the exact same httpd.conf file in my fresh install. It works just fine now. I don't understand why though because it's essentially the same thing.